What happens if a campaign/sector is completely liberated/lost to the enemies?
In Helldivers 2, each campaign and sector has a liberation percentage.

For example, in the image above, the Angel's Venture campaign is ~42% liberated, and the Orion Sector is ~92% liberated.
What happens if the campaign/sector is fully liberated or lost to the enemies?

When a sector is fully liberated or lost, the front moves, and the next planet in the star map (according to the links visible between the planets) will become the new frontline. The sector's color on the starmap will reflect whether or not it is controlled by Super Earth or its enemies.
Functionally, this doesn't change anything gameplay-wise apart from the planet you'll click on to find missions. Sometimes, Major Orders give bonus rewards for sucessfully pushing back the enemy to the next sector and you could similarly lose out on rewards for not successfully defending against a sector's invasion.
